# Rolling Average based on n value in a column

Tags: sql, presto, rolling-computation

I have a table with following structure -

```
| date1       | grp    | value | n |
|:-----------:|:------:|:-----:|:-:|
| 2023-10-01  | g1     | 10    | 30|
| 2023-10-02  | g1     | 15    | 30|
| 2023-10-03  | g1     | 12    | 30|
| 2023-10-01  | g2     | 18    | 10|
| 2023-10-02  | g3     | 12    | 10|
| 2023-10-03  | g4     | 19    | 10|
```

I want to calculate the rolling avg of value column for last n days, where n = the value from column n
which means for g1, I want to calculate last 30 days rolling average while for g2, I want to calculate last 10 days rolling average.

unable to get thru my presto sql query -

```
SELECT 
    date1, 
    grp, 
    n, 
    AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY date1 ROWS BETWEEN CAST(n AS INT) PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS PRIMARY
FROM tbl
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

I get an error with the above query
GROUP BY clause cannot contain aggregations, window functions or grouping operations

Is there a solution for such usecase?

Comment: You would need to run the window function first in a subquery, then use `group by` **BUT** Using the variable n might not be possible through window functions see: https://dbfiddle.uk/EXZynNCR (Postgres not Presto) `argument of ROWS must not contain variables`  but I would not be surprised if Presto had a similar limitation.

Comment: Is it Presto or Trino. Are you running the query agains AWS Athena? Do you have gaps in data?

Comment: Why do you need grouping? Is it possible to have multiple values per date1-grp?

Comment: Is it Presto or Trino - Presto
Do you have gaps in data? No
Why do you need grouping? What do you suggest
Is it possible to have multiple values per date1-grp? No

Answer (score 0):

Amended answer:

If the value of n is highly variable, then perhaps using `row_number()` through a CTE (or subquery), then joining to that result will allow you to restrict the average calculation to within the wanted number of rows per grp. e.g:

```
with tplus as (
  select
         grp as grp2
       , row_number() over(partition by grp order by date1 DESC) as rn
  from tbl
  )
select
       tbl.grp
     , tbl.date1
     , avg(tbl.value) over(partition by tbl.grp) avg_val
     , count(*) over(partition by tbl.grp) rws
     , tbl.n
from tbl
left join tplus on tbl.grp = tplus.grp2 and tbl.n <= tplus.rn
order by
       tbl.grp
     , tbl.date1
```

Note the left join is needed if there are fewer rows than the value of n.

You can summarise te results using select distinct e.g:

```
with tplus as (
  select
         grp as grp2
       , row_number() over(partition by grp order by date1 DESC) as rn
  from tbl
  )
select distinct
       tbl.grp
     , max(tbl.date1) over(partition by grp)     date1
     , avg(tbl.value) over(partition by tbl.grp) avg_val
     , count(*) over(partition by tbl.grp)       rws
     , tbl.n
from tbl
left join tplus on tbl.grp = tplus.grp2 and tbl.n <= tplus.rn
order by
       tbl.grp
```

| grp | date1 | avg_val | rws | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| g1 | 2023-10-03 | 12.3333333333333333 | 30 | 30 |
| g2 | 2023-10-01 | 18.0000000000000000 | 1 | 10 |
| g3 | 2023-10-02 | 12.0000000000000000 | 1 | 10 |
| g4 | 2023-10-03 | 19.0000000000000000 | 1 | 10 |

Working fiddle for these queries (with additional test) data [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ieSWYBcF)

---

I don't use Presto, so the following is in Postgres, but I believe it should apply.

The error stated in your question is solved by running the window function before you attempt a group by on that column. i.e. run the window function in a subquery (or CTE) and then you can refer to that column in a subsequent group by. However you could also use MAX() on that instead (as seen below). An alternative would be to simply use select distinct instead of grouping - but grouping does offer more possibilities.

Also note it is unlikely that you can use a variable inside the window function to alter how many rows are considered, but you could use a case expression to mimic this e.g:

```
SELECT
      date1
    , grp
    , max(av_value)
FROM (
    SELECT
          date1
        , grp
        , n
        , case
            when n = 30 then
               avg(value) over(partition by grp order by date1 
                               rows between 30 preceding and current row)
            when n = 20 then
               avg(value) over(partition by grp order by date1 
                               rows between 20 preceding and current row)
            when n = 10 then
               avg(value) over(partition by grp order by date1 
                               rows between 10 preceding and current row)
          end as av_value
    FROM tbl
    ) d
GROUP BY
      date1
    , grp
```

| date1 | grp | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-03 | g1 | 12.3333333333333333 |
| 2023-10-01 | g1 | 10.0000000000000000 |
| 2023-10-02 | g3 | 12.0000000000000000 |
| 2023-10-03 | g4 | 19.0000000000000000 |
| 2023-10-02 | g1 | 12.5000000000000000 |
| 2023-10-01 | g2 | 18.0000000000000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zgyXc7yo)

Comment: though this solves the problem but cannot be scaled. n value is very very random (I mean wont be 30,20,10)

Comment: have you tried using `n` in the window function? i.e. `rows between n preceding and current row` it does not work in Postgres but "maybe" it's allowed in Presto?  I suspect not but worth trying.

Comment: I have added a new approach to your problem that avoids use of n within the window functions, instead it uses a CTE/subquery and join to vary the number of rows accessed according to n